# Invoke signalR method inside the client method

Tags: c#, signalr, console-application, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I am using signalR version 2.1.2. And I am using console application as a SignalrClient. I invoke a method-A and after getting response , I have to invoke method-B based on the response from method-A. In this scenario I am able to successfully invoke and not getting any response from method-B. Whats my mistake??. Here my code

```
var hubConnection = new HubConnection("Url");

IHubProxy proxy = hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("HitProxy");
proxy.On<bool>("Client-method-B", (retvAl) =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("Method-B response");
});

proxy.On<bool>("Client-method-A", (isConnected) =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("Method-A response");
    if(isConnected)
    {
        proxy.Invoke("method-B", "someValue").Wait();
    }
});

hubConnection.Start().Wait();
proxy.Invoke("method-A", "123").Wait();
```

Here I am not getting any response from 'method-B'. Thanks.

Comment: You should post your Hub code, there could be an issue there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way to get the result from the SignalR server method is to read its return value instead of invoking a client method at the caller side. For example, you may read the response from the method-A as follows:

```
proxy.Invoke("method-A", "123").ContinueWith((t) =>
{
  bool isConnected = t.Result;
});
```

Expecting the signature of method-A is something like:

```
public bool method-A(string p);
```

This way you don't have to invoke a client method just to return the result of a server method to the caller. You may invoke another server method from the callback of another server method call like this:

```
proxy.Invoke("method-A", "123").ContinueWith((t) =>
{
  bool isConnected = t.Result;
  if(isConnected)
  {
    proxy.Invoke("method-B", "someValue").ContinueWith((u) =>
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Method-B response: " + u.Result);
    });
  }
});
```

Assumes that method-B returns a string value at the server side.

Comment: Thanks @XmindZ Its working fine............:) And one more point You should call wait() method to receive the result... That is 
>proxy.Invoke("method-B", "someValue").ContinueWith((u) => 
{ Console.WriteLine("Method-B response: " + u.Result); }).wait(); 
Then only we can able to receive the result from calling method –

Answer (score 2):

In the code supplied you create the proxy

```
IHubProxy proxy = hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("HitProxy");
```

but later u use

```
hubProxy.Invoke("method-B", "someValue").Wait();
```

so is it just a type and proxy == hubProxy ?

I would advice yout to do 3 things

1. use wireshark to check if there is any actual traffic to server when invoking method B
2. check the server side if the server properly invokes the operation
3. you might want to try to dispatch operation B so it's not invoke in the callback context - depending on your app you might want to use Dispatcher or just Task.Run. I'm not sure about signalr client but some frameworks don't like when you invoke their methods in callbacks.

Comment: Hi Lukasz I edited my question. I just tried to use Dispatch event to by pass the current thread. Is it correct?

Comment: Suresh one thing I noticed: in the callback you use 

proxy.Invoke("method-B", "someValue").Wait();

so you are blocking on the thread that signalr probably uses for sending message to server. 

No sure waht you mean by "I just tried to use Dispatch event to by pass the current thread"? Try to use Task.Run for start ok?

sth like Task.Run(() => proxy.Invoke("method-B", "someValue").Wait());

Comment: I am using this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => Testmethod())) in 'Client-method-A'. In this method 'Testmethod', I will invoke 'method-B'  and 'Client-method-B' will call immediately. Is this approach is correct?

Comment: That depends. You see the main problem in your code, I belive, is calling .Wait() in context of the thread that is used by signalR client to perform the call. Using Dispatch.Invoke might help, still remember that using static Invoke call will use current thread dispatcher, so not sure what it exactly would be in your case (for example for console application there is no default Dispatcher created).